# Error in uploading release build from xamarin visual studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to upload an Android build from xamarin visual studio 2019 for MAC

I have linked the Google developer account with visual studio

I expect to upload the Android build but when trying to upload form visual studio it shows me the following error:

> Google Play requires you to manually upload your first APK for this app. You can use an Ad-Hoc APK for this.

And after that I tried to upload manually an ad-hoc build to play developer console in Alpha it gives me the following error:

> You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play.

I'm stuck here and didn't find any solution for that, any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: disable debugging in the build settings for AdHoc.  Or manually create a release build and upload it.

Comment: @Jason can you please tell how to create a release build manually because I'm new to xamarin

Comment: the process you used to generate a build to upload to Google should leave the release APK package somewhere on your system.  Or just select project properties, go to build settings, and disable debugging for the ad-hoc build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. That is correct that you have to manually upload your first APK. All you got to do now is

1. Change the project configuration from Debug to Release, (as shown in the picture) [image: Image of Visual Studio]
2. Then Rebuild your App in Release mode, and
3. Then Archive for Publishing.

Double check to see that no one has enabled debugging in Release Mode of your App by

1. Opening the Android project options
2. Select Compiler options -> Configuration:Release -> Debug Information: None & Define Symbols: {Does not have DEBUG}
3. Press Ok. Rebuild and Re-archive if you had to make changes

PPS: Make sure that you upload a [64-bit version](https://medium.com/swlh/64-bit-version-of-your-xamarin-native-or-xamarin-forms-android-app-477d0e637432) of your app too

Comment: After adding the ad-hoc build then I change the build number and try to upload a built form visual studio it gives me the following error:
>Error Uploading. A task was canceled.

Comment: That's a different issue, but could you please share the data in the Output that came when you were uploading?

Comment: Could you please share as much details of the error as possible?

Comment: I fixed it as it was because the ad-hoc build uploaded need to have privacy policy link after that it was uploaded successfully.
Thanks for your help really appreciated